# C++ ctime() to date formatted string?

Tags: c++, date, datetime, formatting, unix-timestamp

I am trying to change format of my unix timestamp. But I don't see any option to customize the format.

This is my code:

```
tempstring = "Your last login was: ";
time_t lastLogin = player->getLastLoginSaved(); // &lastLogin = Unix timestamp

tempstring += ctime(&lastLogin);
tempstring.erase(tempstring.length() -1);
tempstring += ".";
AddTextMessage(msg, MSG_STATUS_DEFAULT, tempstring.c_str());
```

This will give me an output of:

```
Your last login was: Sun Sep 29 02:41:40 2019.
```

How can I change this to a format like this instead?

```
Your last login was: 29. Sep 2019 02:41:40 CET.
```

I believe the format would be: `%d. %b %Y %H:%M:%S CET`

But how can I do that with ctime()? Please let me know if there is any way to change format. I am new with C++ so if I need another library please let me know.

Comment: Check `locale` and the support for it when using the functions you are using. If you are going to present something for a user - do it in accordance with their `locale`.

Comment: I want it to be that format regardless what format the computer uses. Is there any way I can convert my `&lastLogin` to the format I mentioned? @TedLyngmo

Comment: Sort of ... With the current standard you'll have to do it yourself (or by using a library) but in C++20, `<chrono>` willl likely have been expanded to include these things. Most of Howard Hinnants library will probably be there so, just download and use it: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: I'm curious if your intention is to always output using the computer's currently set local time zone, or if you need to output using a time zone that always (or currently) has CET as its abbreviation.  Currently there are only two time zones where "29. Sep 2019 02:41:40 CET" is a valid time stamp:  Africa/Algiers and Africa/Tunis.  Is one of these time zones the one that you always want to use?  Or is CET just an example abbreviation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use time.h.
Breakdown your `time_t` into a `struct tm`.

```c
struct tm *localtime(const time_t *clock);

struct tm {
    int tm_sec;         /* seconds */
    int tm_min;         /* minutes */
    int tm_hour;        /* hours */
    int tm_mday;        /* day of the month */
    int tm_mon;         /* month 0 to 11*/
    int tm_year;        /* years since 1900*/
    int tm_wday;        /* day of the week 0 to 6*/
    int tm_yday;        /* day in the year 0 to 365*/
    int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
};
```

Then format with `sprintf`, remembering to add offsets. E.g. `snprintf(cTimeStr, sizeof(cTimeStr), "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);`

Use const char arrays or string array to get month as a string.

See also: https://zetcode.com/articles/cdatetime/